# About the notation of Axiom of Regularity

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Axiom of Regularity/Foundation

> ∀ ( ≠ ∅ → ∃ ( ∈  ∧  ⋂  = ∅))
>
> This says that every non-empty set must contain a set that shares no
> elements with it.

So, how do we understand axiom of regularity is talking about a set with "y" just from the notation?

(I think using intersection ⋂ gives a clue that y is a set because only sets intersects not elements but not sure if its right inference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's less here than meets the eye. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, **everything** is a set. So $y$ is a set because it can't not be.

(This is the source of the most common criticism of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, incidentally: that formalizing mathematics in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ inevitably leads to "junk theorems." See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems) for example.)

Comment: Which axiom or axioms define everything as set? How do we deduce this?

Comment: @lockedscope $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a first-order theory, with only one "kind" of object; *set* is just the English name we give to that kind. See also Noah Schweber's comment below.

Comment: @lockedscope Well, the term "set" isn't even part of the language of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so really this is just something we say on the intuitive side of things. In particular, the question "How do we know that $y$ is a set?" can't even be *asked* in the language of set theory. That said, the relevant axiom is **extensionality**: it says that $\in$ captures everything about each object. Together with the fact that $\in$ is the only symbol in the language of set theory, so objects can only relate to each other through it, we have in a reasonable sense that everything is a set.